# Targeting a multi dimensional associative array part by index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**How can I target a multi-dimensional associative array by index?** I need to be able to do something along the lines of this...

```
$x=2;

$assoc_array = array(
"red" => array(1,2,3,4,5),
"green" => array(1,2,3,4,5),
"blue" => array(1,2,3,4,5)
);

array_push($assoc_array[$x],6);
```

Comment: Well, actually an associative array's **indexes are** `'red'`, `'green'`, `'blue'` in your example.

Comment: I would like to push a value into the array within the second array slot which is the 'green' array.

Comment: done, see below for my answer. To do what you want, $x should be 1 since arrays starts with 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually *can* do that. As an alternative, you can use `$assoc_array[$x][] = 6`

**EDIT**: The above is the answer for what you asked. The code below is for what I think you need, but didn't state clearly:

```
$x = 2;
$keys = array_keys($assoc_array);
var_dump($assoc_array[$keys[$x]]);
```

Working codepad example: http://codepad.org/QXfHmKH8

Comment: @pagewil @GabiPurcaru That doesn't work. http://codepad.org/nZLB9E8g You're dispensing incorrect advice.

Comment: @FinfalForm what exactly does not work? It's working as the OP asked as far as I can see.

Comment: +1 Was just posting the same. @pagewil: I have to note that if you have to do this your code has design problems.

Comment: This doesn't do what OP is asking for.

Comment: @imoda and what is the OP asking for? he accepted the answer, so I'd say it is.

Comment: He wants to add `6` into an existing array within an array based on the order of the keys.  What your code is doing is creating a new key value within the first level of the array.  The value `6` should be called with `$assoc_array['green'][5]` not `$assoc_array[2][0]`

Answer (score 1):

My proof that it works: http://codepad.org/G81fsTzl

Red being 0, green being 1, and blue being 2 or the $x=2 part.

If my answer is correct, be sure to check the checkbox to the left of this post so I can gain points. Points are what motivates me to continue to answer questions. Thank you for your time.

```
$x=2;

$assoc_array = array(
    "red" => array(1,2,3,4,5),
    "green" => array(1,2,3,4,5),
    "blue" => array(1,2,3,4,5)
);

$c = 0;
foreach ($assoc_array as $key => $value)
{
    if ($c == $x)
    {
        array_push($value, 6);
        $assoc_array[$key] = $value;
    }

    $c++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must reference them via the key which in this case is the colour values you have given. To add a new element to the first item (red) you would use:

```
$assoc_array["red"][] = 6;
```

Using $assoc_array[$x][] = 6; will create a new array key with the identifier of $x unless $x is either red, green or blue.

The above method works but is massively convoluted if you just wish to reference an existing array value.

Part of the idea of giving a string value as an array key is to allow the easy reference of the array values via a related string rather than a meaningless number.